# Is it a good idea to use Hawaii as a database timezone?

Tags: database-design, timezone

Because they don't use DST it would be easier to convert timezones, no?

Comment: If you can use arbitrary timezones why not UTC?

Comment: UTC by definition has no DST. It also has a zero offset from GMT. But I guess Hawaii sounds better. :)

Comment: What if Hawaii gets DST in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better would be to use [Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

Answer (score 2):

One state doth not a standard make.

Indiana is split between Central and Eastern time.  Some parts of Indiana used to observe daylight savings time, and some parts didn't. Those parts had nothing to do with the time zone. They had to do with proximity to metro areas in adjacent states.

*Each county* effectively decided which time zone it was going to be in, and whether it was going to observe daylight savings time.

In 2006 all of Indiana started following daylight saving time. But 18 counties are still on Central time, and the rest are on Eastern time.

Man, I love politics. Coordinated Universal Time is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

This is what [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) is for